# Definition of saveKey in jqGrid('navGrid')

Tags: jqgrid

Is it possible to close the Add-dialogue after clicking Submit-button? I didn't find such property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the option [closeAfterAdd:true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties). You should add the option as a part of your `prmAdd` parameter of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#definition)

```
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('navGrid','#gridpager',{parameters},
    prmEdit, prmAdd, prmDel, prmSearch, prmView);
```

For example,

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
    {del:false},           // parameters
    {},                    // edit parameters
    {closeAfterAdd:true}); // add parameters
```

Comment: Oleg, it works perfect. Thanks a lot! I looked at documentation page several times, but didn't check it. Thanks